# Issues with simple_form_for and nomethoderror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I am new to rails and am trying to create a form with simple form and am having issues with it accepting the controller, model, and view. I wanted to use the new_event method but at first I wanted to just get it working.  I actually want to format it much better. Thank you in advance. Here is the error with trace:

```
NoMethodError in EventsController#new

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/saasbook/Documents/ronde

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
  app/models/event.rb:36:in `validate'
  app/models/event.rb:25:in `new_event'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:20:in `new'
```

Here is the model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

   # Associations
   has_many :invitations
   belongs_to :created_by, :class_name => 'User'
   has_many :attending_users, :through => :invitations, :source => :user, :conditions => "status = 'confirmed'"
   has_many :invited_users, :through => :invitations, :source => :invited_user, :conditions => "status = 'invited'"

   validates_presence_of :description, :location, :name, :start, :created_by
   attr_accessible :description, :end, :location, :name, :public, :start, :created_by, :event_type, :user_id
   EVENT_OPTIONS = %w[food drink other]
   after_initialize :init

   def init
     self.public ||= false
   end

   def new
     self.create(:description, :end, :location, :name, :public, :start, :created_by, :event_type, :user_id)
   end

   def self.new_event(details, user)
      @event = Event.new
      @event.created_by = user
      @flag = validate(details)
      if @flag.empty?
         @event.attributes = details
         @event.save!
      end
      return @event, @flag
   end
   def self.validate(details)
flag = {}
flag['name'] = true if details[:name] == nil or details[:name] == ""
flag['description'] = true if details[:description] == nil or details[:description] == ""
flag['location'] = true if details[:location] == nil or details[:location] == ""
flag['event_type'] = true if details[:event_type] == nil or details[:event_type] == ""
return flag
```

end
And here is my controller and view:

```
 def new

 end

def create
    @event = Event.new 
    @event.created_by = current_user
    @event.attributes = params[:event]
    @event.save!
    redirect_to user_dashboard_path
end
```

and

```
%body   
 .container
    %h2.title Create New Event 
    = simple_form_for(Event.new, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |form|
        = f.hidden :created_by => current_user
        = f.text_field :name,:placeholder => "What should we do?"
        = f.text_area :description, rows: 3, :placeholder => "Give your friends some more details and convince them to come "
        = f.text_field :location,:placeholder => "Where?"
        = f.collection_select :event_type, Event::EVENT_OPTIONS, :to_s, :humanize, prompt: true
        = f.datetime_select :start, :default => Time.now, :discard_month => true, :discard_year => true, :ampm => true, :minute_step =>15
        = f.datetime_select :end, :default => Time.now, :discard_month => true, :discard_year => true, :ampm => true, :minute_step =>15
        = f.submit value: 'create', class: 'btn btn-large btn-success'
```

Comment: Your `event.rb` code seems truncated. The stack references a `validate` method at line 36, but you're not even showing that many lines and there is no matching `end` to the `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you defining a "new" method in your model? That's one of those sacred rails words so you really shouldn't redefine it, especially since it looks like you're not actually doing anything different with it. Also, you're making 'new' an instance method instead of a class method, meaning you can't call Event.new but rather Event.find(1).new, which won't really work because then the event would have to already have been created. For more info: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

So basically, get rid of your "new" instance method in the model. Then I would change the following code:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new params[:event] # this grabs the params (and values) from the form
  ## @event.created_by = current_user - don't need this because you have a hidden field for it
  ## @event.attributes = params[:event] - unnecessary, you need to be defining your strong paramters below anyway if you're using rails 4
  if @event.save!   
    redirect_to user_dashboard_path
  else
    #fail miserably
end
```